# JSF: store form data to a map

Tags: forms, jsf, dictionary

I'm developing a JSF page that contains a form with a lot of input string values. I don't want to create a corresponding field in the bean for each input . Is it possible to use a map instead.

Here's what i want my form input element to look like:

```
<h:inputText value='#{myBean.data["key"]}' /> // or something like this
```

And the bean contains the map as follows:

```
class myBean {
Map data;

...
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is. What exactly is the problem you're facing? That's a more interesting question for Stack Overflow than such a rhetorical Yes-No question.

Comment: What should getter and setter for map operation look like if I create such a code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *What should getter and setter for map operation look like if I create such a code?*

Nothing special. Just a standard getter as you should always use for model properties.

```
public Map<String, Object> getData() {
    return data;
}
```

A setter is not mandatory as it won't be used anyway. EL will use map's own `put()` method for that. You only need to make sure that the map is already precreated in bean's (post)constructor, JSF/EL won't do that for you.

```
public MyBean() {
    data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
}
```